# Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined - while upgrading jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-3

We are using jquery 1.11.1 four application and upgrading to jquery 3.3.1.
For all the hyperlinks, on click facing "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined". This is when I upgrade jquery UI to 1.12.1 and 1.12.0. But this works fine with lower jquery version. 
What could be the issue? Please help.

```
        <a href="javascript:applyTest(0)" class="blue" id="msg_none"></a>
```

Stacktrace :

```
jquery-1.12.4.js:1474 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
    at Function.Sizzle.contains (jquery-1.12.4.js:1474)
    at $.(:8787/myapplication/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseCapture (http://localhost:8787/resources/js/plugin/jquery-ui.js:11086:38)
    at $.(:8787/myapplication/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseCapture (http://localhost:8787/resources/js/plugin/jquery-ui.js:144:25)
    at $.(:8787/myapplication/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDown (http://localhost:8787/resources/js/plugin/jquery-ui.js:9352:42)
    at $.(:8787/myapplication/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDown (http://localhost:8787/resources/js/plugin/jquery-ui.js:144:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:9307)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
Sizzle.contains @ jquery-1.12.4.js:1474
_mouseCapture @ jquery-ui.js:11086
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:144
_mouseDown @ jquery-ui.js:9352
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:144
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:9307
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also encountering this issue

Comment: It looks like after resolving other errors with jQuery upgrade, this one eventually got away. Didn't do anything particular for this one. @eatorres